# Changing bone size changes Envelope instead

Tags: bones

I try to change the bone size:
[image]

See also this video:
https://youtu.be/cZ3o5tjO51s?t=403

But for me the tool is only changing the envelope, what am I doing wrong?
[image]

(blender 2.91)

Comment: The title contains the word Curve.  The body makes no mention of curve.  That does not seem to make sense.  I suggest you rewrite your question to make it easier to understand.   Please place [your] work in the question as a screen capture and label the work.  Are these screen captures from the video ... which has no problem?

Comment: I want to make a screencapture, but OBS can only record 1/4th of my display due to a DPI bug. I will try to make a screencapture on another machine.

Comment: OBS?  BSE?  You can capture a screen and edit with GIMP or Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  to change the size of a bendy bone.